# is there a Ruby way to substitute the last four digits of a string, excluding spaces?

Tags: regex, ruby, string, substitution

I have to find a way to anonymize the last four numerical characters. Presented with a phone number string like "+36 6 41 88 75 22" (or any other format, like "+36641887522" or +36 6 418 875 22 and so forth), I want my code to output "+36 6 41 88 XX XX".

`phoneNumber = "+36 6 41 88 75 22"`
The closest regex I've found to my desired selection is : 
`/\d.{4}$/`
which is convenient enough, since `lastFour = phone.scan(/\d.{4}$/).join` equals "75 22", including the space.

Now I want to substitute all numbers (not the space!) with an "X", but

```
phoneNumber.gsub(/\d.{4}$/, "X")
```

outputs "+36 6 41 88 X", and I want my code to output "+36 6 41 88 XX XX".

I have also tried the following cumbersome solution :

```
phoneNumber = "+36 6 41 88 75 22"
def anonymizer(phone)
    lastFour = phone.scan(/\d.{4}$/).join
    anonFour = lastFour.chars
    anonFour.each do |digit|
        digit.gsub(/[0-9]/, "X")
    end
    puts "attempted transform #{anonFour}"
    phone.gsub(lastFour, anonFour.join)
end


phoneyNumber = anonymizer(phoneNumber)
puts phoneyNumber
```

to no avail, since it returns the number as is ("+36 6 41 88 75 22" instead of "+36 6 41 88 XX XX")

Comment: You need to clarify (by editing your question) the pattern(s) the phone number may have. You give an example where the last six characters are ' dd dd', where 'd' represents a digit. If you are only interested in that pattern the solution is easy. I hope that other patterns for the last four digits are possible (e.g., 'd d dd' or 'd, ext. ddd'), as that would make it a much more interesting question. If the second interpretation is possible it would suffice to give a second example that has a different pattern for at least the last four digits.

Comment: Yes, I haven't specified that my solution needs to be flexible. It has to work for +12 3 456 789 01 as with 123 456 7890 and all other formats

Comment: [Both my solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59811903/3832970) handle those formats you specified correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your string contains only a phone number that ends with 'dd dd', where `d` is a digit, you don't need a regular expression:

```
'+36 6 41 88 75 22'[0..-6] + 'XX XX'
  #=> "+36 6 41 88 XX XX"
```

I assume, however, the more interesting interpretation of the "last four numerical characters", that successive pairs of digits can be separated zero or more non-digits. In that case, the following is a simple way to make the desired substitutions.

```
def sub_last4(str)
  n = str.count('0-9')
  str.gsub(/\d/) { |s| (n -= 1) <= 3 ? 'X' : s }
end
```

```
sub_last4 '+36 6 41 88 75 22'
  #=> "+36 6 41 88 XX XX" 
sub_last4 '+36 6 41 88 7522'
  #=> "+36 6 41 88 XXXX"
sub_last4 '+36 6 how 41 8 now 8 75 2 brown 5 cow'
  #=> "+36 6 how 41 8 now 8 XX X brown X cow"
sub_last4 'SY-0-6447'
  #=> "SY-0-XXXX"
```

Here's a second way.

```
def sub_last4(str)
  4.times.each_with_object(str.dup) { |_,s|
    s[s.rindex(/\d/)] = 'X' }
end
```

Comment: I need this to work with all kinds of phone number formats, be it 12 23 34 45 56, 122 334 4556 or 1223344556, so the first solution is not an option. The second one nailed it tho!

Comment: The first solution nailed it, and I have been trying to better understand the syntax of this one-liner, ``` { |s| (n -= 1) <= 3 ? 'X' : s } ``` which looks a bit cryptic.

Comment: `gsub` passes each match of one digit to its block, setting the block variable `s` equal to that match. The block computes the string that will replace `s`. The block is equivalent to `{ |s| n -= 1; n <= 3 ? 'X' : s }`. `n` is first reduced by `1` then the block returns `’X’` if `n <= 3`, else it returns `s`. In the latter case, since `s` is replaced with itself, the digit is not modified.

Comment: `str.count('0123456789')` could be replaced with `str.count('0-9')`

Comment: @3limin4t0r, that's very interesting. I did an edit. I was not aware of the variety of arguments that [String#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-count) could take. An example for readers: `str = "my dog has fleas"; str.count 'sadh', '^g-i' #=> 5`, as it is counting the number of characters that are in the string `'sadh'` and *not* in the string `'ghi'`. That would be the letters in the string `'sad'`, of which `str` contains 2 `'s'`'s, 2 `'a'`'s and 1 `'d'`, for a total of `5`...

Comment: ...Moreover, the [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html) instance methods `delete`, `delete!`, `squeeze` and `squeeze!` appear to also take string arguments (optional for `squeeze` and `squeeze!`) that are intersected in the same way as described above for `count`.

Answer (score 4):

You may use

```
phoneNumber = phoneNumber.gsub(/\d(?=(?:\D*\d){0,3}\D*\z)/, 'X')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hKDD4C/1) and the [online Ruby demo](https://rextester.com/KHCOQ90361).

**Details**

- `\d` - a digit...
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){0,3}\D*\z)` - that is immediately followed with

  - `(?:\D*\d){0,3}` - 0 to 3 consecutive occurrences of

    - `\D*` - 0+ non-digit chars
    - `\d` - a digit
  - `\D*` - 0+ non-digit chars
  - `\z` - end of string (`$` matches end of a line in a Ruby regex).

Another idea: match the last four digits with any chars other than digits and then replace just those digits with `X`:

```
phoneNumber.gsub(/(?:\d\D*){4}\z/) { $~[0].gsub(/\d/, 'X') }
```

See [this Ruby demo](https://rextester.com/SWB31063)

Here, `(?:\d\D*){4}\z` matches four consecutive occurrences of a digit and any 0+ non-digit chars at the end of the string, and `$~[0]` in the `gsub` block represents the whole match value where `.gsub(/\d/, 'X')` replaces each digit with `X`.

Comment: Wonderfully explained regex, unluckily my question wasn't perfectly clear as to the many possible formats of the phone number string, so this actually only covers some of the possibilities.

Comment: @WildWilyWilly What kind of strings doesn't my code cover? It covers all the possibilities, even punctuation between numbers.

Comment: Dang, sorry you were definitely right although my question wasn't fully developed.

Comment: My bad, I should have tested this on my code instead of the lousy regex app I used

Answer (score 0):

You could reverse the string, then substitute a single digit with `'X'` four times.

```
phone_number = '+36 6 41 88 75 22'

phone_number.reverse!
4.times { phone_number.sub!(/\d/, 'X') }
phone_number.reverse!

phone_number
#=> "+36 6 41 88 XX XX"
```

Note that I use mutating methods here, if you don't want to mutate the original replace the first `phone_number.reverse!` with `phone_number = phone_number.reverse`. Which will create a new string that is safe to act on by the other mutating methods.

You could replace `phone_number.sub!(/\d/, 'X')` with `phone_number[/\d/] = 'X'` depending on preference.